# WebView in ViewFlipper doesn't get swipe gestures

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, viewflipper

**What I need:** I need to have different WebViews inside a ViewFlipper and then I want to have gestureListening on ViewFlipper for Swipe actions on Left Right switching.

**What I have:** I have added WebViews in ViewFlipper and they are getting loaded.

**What is the problem:** When I want to swipe left/right, it doesn't work and WebViews do not get changed. When I test the same ViewFlipper and code with ImageViews, it works fine.

What can be the issue with WebViews in ViewFlipper?

Comment: WebView has its own gestures. You can't use it inside a flipper with gesture unless you override the webView's gestures

Comment: Please check this question,help needed   https://stackoverflow.com/q/50617100/6299045

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add this code on your activity

```
@Override
 public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
 {
     super.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
     return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and the above did not work for me because I had other navigation buttons in my activity, and the dispatchTouchEvent overrode all of them as well.  I finally broke down and created a custom WebView and used it instead of WebView

```
CustomWebView m_webview = new CustomWebView(this);
//normal webview code here
```

Then create a custom webview to handle swiping

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView
{
    private final int MINIMUM_HORIZONTAL_DISTANCE = 150;
    private final int MAXIMUM_VERTICAL_DISTANCE = 100;

    float downXValue, downYValue;
    private float lastTouchX, lastTouchY;
    private boolean hasMoved = false;

    public CustomWebView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
    {
        boolean consumed = super.onTouchEvent(touchevent);

        if (isClickable())
        {
            switch (touchevent.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    lastTouchX = touchevent.getX();
                    lastTouchY = touchevent.getY();
                    downXValue = touchevent.getX();
                    downYValue = touchevent.getY();
                    hasMoved = false;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    hasMoved = moved(touchevent);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    float currentX = touchevent.getX();
                    float currentY = touchevent.getY();
                    float X_difference = Math.abs(downXValue - currentX);
                    float Y_difference = Math.abs(downYValue - currentY);

                    /**
                    * Next WebView
                    */
                    if (lastTouchX < currentX && X_difference > MINIMUM_HORIZONTAL_DISTANCE && Y_difference < MAXIMUM_VERTICAL_DISTANCE)
                    {
                        //Your ViewFlipper Code here   viewFlipper.showNext();
                    }

                    /**
                    * Previous WebView
                    */
                    if (lastTouchX > currentX && X_difference > MINIMUM_HORIZONTAL_DISTANCE && Y_difference < MAXIMUM_VERTICAL_DISTANCE)
                    {
                        //Your ViewFlipper Code here   viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return consumed || isClickable();
    }

    private boolean moved(MotionEvent evt)
    {
        return hasMoved || Math.abs(evt.getX() - lastTouchX) > 10.0;
    }
}
```